# position argument in seaborn violinplot unclear

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Beautiful *and* useful plots, this seaborn.

I am trying to position violinplots on the abcissa, as the distributions I am investigating depend on a numerical parameter. Should really be quite easy with

```
import matplotlib as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
y = list()
for n in (10, 100, 1000):
    rs = np.random.RandomState(0);
    y.append(rs.normal(0, 2, n))
sns.violinplot(data=y, positions=(0, 5, 7))
```

if I want the abcissa positions of the violins to be at 0, 5 and 7, respectively. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27322650/how-to-use-seaborn-pointplot-and-violinplot-in-the-same-figure-change-xticks-a) answer mwaskom points out that violinplot takes a `positions` argument. Regardless of what I do, such as passing a numpy array or tuple, the positions of the violinplots remain the same and seem to be assigned to an increasing integer starting with 0.

Comment: The positions argument was removed from `violinplot` a few versions ago, unfortunately.

Comment: But there is a relevant answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090425/seaborn-boxplots-at-desired-distances-along-the-x-axis

Comment: Fanstastic! I hadn't seen that post. If you change your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.